# How can I scroll a XUL tree element by less than a whole row?

Tags: scroll, tree, xul

I've got a XUL tree element, and would like to scroll the rows up and down on a per-pixel basis, instead of by whole rows, if possible.

Browsing through the source to [mozilla-central](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/content/widgets/tree.xml#688), and Thunderbird's copy at [comm-central](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-1.9.2/source/mozilla/toolkit/content/widgets/tree.xml#660), it looks like I can only scroll by rows, but I guess I'm hoping that I missed something.

(The other option I saw was to wrap the whole tree in a scrollbox, but that would end up scrolling the headers, which I don't really want to do.)

Thanks,
Blake.

Comment: I think just clicking the arrows on the scrollbar will move it just a few pixels. But I'm assuming you want a programmatic solution?

Comment: You would think so, but clicking the arrows scrolls it by entire rows at a time.  :(